# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. WebBrowser C# Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Below is my Code

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somewebsite.com/login");
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", "mylogin");
        doc.GetElementById("pass").SetAttribute("value", "123456");
        doc.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somewebsite.com/newpage");

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        doc.GetElementById("title").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
        doc.GetElementById("content").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
        doc.GetElementById("new-format").InvokeMember("click");
        doc.GetElementById("check").InvokeMember("click");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("jj").SetAttribute("value", "01");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aa").SetAttribute("value", "2013");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hh").SetAttribute("value", "01");
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
        doc.GetElementById("publish").InvokeMember("click");
        MessageBox.Show("Posted");

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Url != webBrowser1.Url)
            return;

    }
```

The Problem is that I have searched a lot and didn't found any appropriate or authentic way to wait until the browser is done with loading the page.

So, My question is how to wait until the browser loads the page. My program is going to navigate a lot to do some works, so I need the best way to handle this problem?
 Please suggest some

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how your title is a summary of your question. And why is this tagged vb.net?

Comment: Check out the IsBusy Property on the WebBrowser Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [documentCompleted](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=documentcompleted%20webbrowser%20c%23&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v%3Dvs.110%29.aspx&ei=fB2qUrKZKcahqQGovYCwAg&usg=AFQjCNEbNnlxF0wtu2p8KnqAC6jTT5BCFQ&sig2=-bg8MtakZwDqoPYhwadeag&bvm=bv.57967247,d.aWM) event. That is when the document has completely loaded.

Add the event:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(checkDocument);
```

Check the document:

```
private void checkDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    doc.GetElementById("title").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
    doc.GetElementById("content").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
    doc.GetElementById("new-format").InvokeMember("click");
    doc.GetElementById("check").InvokeMember("click");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("jj").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aa").SetAttribute("value", "2013");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hh").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    doc.GetElementById("publish").InvokeMember("click");
    MessageBox.Show("Posted");

}
```

Comment: I am new to C# and I don't know exactly how documentcompleted works. Please eloborate because I think that when I navigate outside the documentcompleted function, the control transfer to documentcompleted and then when page loads it reads next line like this should work                                                                      webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somewebsite.com/login"); dosomething(); 
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.somewebsite.com/newpage");

Comment: Did this answer your question? Check as answer if so.

Comment: Yes Dear, It answered my question. Thank you......I also wanted to add something that there were two frames and it called checkDocument() two times. So I put a condition in function to avoid the situation

Comment: Also, now I want to call new function on webrowserdocumentcompleted, so should I do like this webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted -=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(checkDocument; and then webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(newCheckDocument);

Answer (score 0):

Add this if statement into your button click event

```
if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
  {
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
    doc.GetElementById("title").SetAttribute("value", textBox1.Text);
    doc.GetElementById("content").SetAttribute("value", textBox2.Text);
    doc.GetElementById("new-format").InvokeMember("click");
    doc.GetElementById("check").InvokeMember("click");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("jj").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("aa").SetAttribute("value", "2013");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("hh").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", "01");
    doc.GetElementById("publish").InvokeMember("click");
    MessageBox.Show("Posted");
  }
```